# How to maximise the odds of becoming Cathar?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

In two separate games, twice I received the event that allows you to become Cathar, and I never received events towards other heresies.

Since I like very much to play as Cathar, I'd like to know how to maximise the chances of getting this event.

As far as I know you just have to be Catholic, and put your Chaplain in your home province to research cultural tech… so, besides having a Chaplain with a high learning, it's just luck?

Was it just happenstance that I twice got to become Cathar and not another heresy, or is this culture dependant? First time I was Irish, second time Breton.

This, assuming there are no other Cathars to be found, of course.

The only DLC I have is Sons of Abraham, and this must work on Ironman mode.

Comment: I always get Lollard for some reason, which sucks because Lollard is boring.

Comment: Failing all else, you could try triggering conversion through the console - there's a `religion` command. http://www.ckiiwiki.com/Console_commands

Comment: @Andrew nice tip, but I'd like this to work on Ironman mode, and in general I'd avoid to cheat if possible.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to become Cathar, I think there are more effective ways of doing this. I can think of two:

- Have your successor educated by a Cathar character (if they are diligent and zealous it will speed up the conversion)
- Invite diligent and zealous Cathar characters to your court - they have an event that can convert random courtiers to their religion (you can then choose to convert)

Also, note that heresy in general spreads faster if moral authority of your religion is low. You can help it along by appointing an anti-pope.

If you really want to stick with the court chaplain research, you can see the chances of his "failure" in the tooltip - failure means he becomes a heretic. I think the game just picks a heresy at random though, so I think this could take a long time.

Comment: The "appointing an anti-pope" is a great suggestion, I totally didn't consider it, thanks! The "education" part is technically correct and would be a good suggestion too, but my premise was that _"there are no other Cathars to be found"_ ;)

Comment: @Lohoris no cathars *anywhere* in the world? A person doesn't need to be your courtier or even part of your realm to educate your kids. They just need to be close enough to interact with you (which is likely the case considering that catholics and their heresies are usually found in the northwest quarter of the world map.)

Comment: @Philipp yes, none. It's pretty common during the first, I don't know, 50 years?